# Do I really need a "certified translation" for the Spanish consulate if my documents are already in Spanish?

Tags: visa, spain

For a longer-than-ninety-days visa to Spain, the Houston Spanish Consulate requires a raft of documents, all with "certified translation into Spanish."

Now if the original is in Spanish, wouldn't they accept that?  I speak and write Spanish, but I'm afraid that if I ask them, they'll get suspicious and reject what I write claiming I wrote it in English and didn't pay a "certified translator" forty bucks a page.

**Update:** My Spanish-speaking lawyer friend says that the translator just has to self-certify that he/she is fluent in the language.  But he apparently based that on requirements of the **U.S.** State Department.

Comment: You can write your own documents in Spanish. It's things like your birth certificate and the like that need a certified translation. If you were born in a county that offers documents in Spanish though, you wouldn't need the translation.

Comment: Can you specify what those documents are? Like @phoog I have mostly seen this requirement in relation to documents you cannot write yourself.

Comment: All of them.  Lease in Spain of course will already be in Spanish.  Police check, health check, proof of income, reason for going, what you want to do, etc.  Long list, and each consulate has their own version of the list.

Comment: @WGroleau Do you have the list for Houston? The [list for LA](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/LOSANGELES/es/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Documents/Residence%20English%20Check%20list.pdf) does not contain anything that suggests you would need to write some documents yourself and have them translated in Spanish. In fact, I don't see any document you could write yourself in there.

Comment: But you obviously need to get a certified translation for all official documents. Implicitly, the assumption is that the originasl would be in English or some other languages, if that's not the case, there is no reason you could not use them.

Comment: @Gala: With the title "Residence Visa," that may be for someone who wants to move to Spain.  Or maybe LA is just looser.  Houston wants a statement of what you want to do, where you plan to stay, etc. along with an actual lease or purchase of a home (pay for a round trip ticket to arrange for a place to live, then come back to apply for permission to live in it).  Tempting to risk being branded a smart-aleck by asking, "Aren't there hotels and campgrounds in Spain?"  Maybe I should move to L.A. before applying.  :-)

Comment: If you did your own translation you could make it say whatever you wanted.  Of course they won't accept that!  On the other hand, if you can do good translation I wouldn't be surprised if you could find a translator that would verify your translations for a lot less than creating them from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot right in the comments, but I'll try to organize what I've learned since the original post.

Presenting a contract for a *vivienda* is not a requirement in the actual law, and a lawyer in Madrid says if I hire her, she'll educate the consulate.

The translations, according to the same lawyer, can only be accepted from someone on an official list.  The list comes from the Spanish government, not any individual consulate.

Items where the original is Spanish don't have to be translated.  (It's obvious, but when dealing with bureaucrats, one should never assume...)

According to the lawyer, presenting a translation for the agency to edit will not save any money.